# Wget Path Environment Variable on Windows

Tags: powershell, command-line, cmd, wget

On Windows 10, I installed [`Wget`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) by [`choco install wget`](https://chocolatey.org/packages/Wget).

Then I added `wget.exe` location folder to Path Environment Variable (which at the time of installation was `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Wget\tools`).

However, Wget commands using PowerShell / cmd, like `wget --help` and `wget [any_link]` don't work right away, they work only if I type `wget.exe --help` and `wget.exe [any_link]`

**`wget --help` error:**

```
wget : The remote name could not be resolved: '--help'
At line:1 char:1
+ wget --help
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

How to disable explicit `.exe` extension? I know it's a minor problem, but when you do not use Wget very often, each time it takes you some time recollecting this annoying detail...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running curl via powershell - how to construct arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30807318/running-curl-via-powershell-how-to-construct-arguments)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove alias in script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24347758/remove-alias-in-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Powershell already has its own wget command defined, that actually is an alias of Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet. If you remove the alias you can use wget.exe command without the file extension. Just try

```
Remove-Item Alias:wget
wget --help
```