# powershell can't use remove-alias

Tags: powershell

When I enter in PowerShell:

```
Remove-Alias -Name someAlias
```

This error shows:

```
Remove-Alias : The term 'Remove-Alias' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Alias -Name someAlias
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Remove-Alias:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Note: someAlias is already in my alias list, I checked this.

Comment: `Remove-Alias` is a cmdlet in PowerShell 6, check you powershell version by `$PSVersionTable`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Powershell 5.1 [docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-alias?view=powershell-5.1#notes) of `New-Alias`:

> Notes
>   To create a new alias, use Set-Alias or New-Alias. To change an alias, use Set-Alias. To delete an alias, use Remove-Item.

So under Powershell 5.x you've to use `Remove-Item`. In stated in above comment `Remove-Alias` is only supported in PowerShell 6.

Check this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24347758/remove-alias-in-script) how an alias is removed via `Remove-Item`.

Comment: Well, that is if you don't have another add-on module\function that provides it. For Example ---   Find-Command -Name Remove-Alias | Format-Table -AutoSize;Get-Command -Name Remove-Ali* | Format-Table -AutoSize

Comment: You should explain at least a little about how to use Remove-Item in this answer instead of just linking to the other answer. I only skimmed this answer and tried running Remove-Item without realizing it actually deletes files.

Comment: TLDR `Remove-Item` removes files. `$Alias` is a PSDrive (`Get-PSDrive Alias`) which is a special data store. `Remove-Item Alias:MyAlias` will get rid of the alias on PSv5.